# Solution of integral $\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}A\sin\left(\frac{ 2\pi\sqrt{(X-x)^2 + (Y-y)^2 + Z^2}}{\lambda}\right) dx dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am working on a simulation experiment on light where I concluded that the magnitude of intensity at each pixel is given by the equation -
$$C_\text{total}=\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}A\sin\left(\frac{
2\pi\sqrt{(X-x)^2 + (Y-y)^2 + Z^2}}{\lambda}\right) dx\space dy$$ where $x$ and $y$ are the variables and rest of the symbols are constants.

---

##### Problem and Motivation

I am unable to solve the double integral expression on the RHS. The solution of this expression will enable achieving highest possible level of accuracy in the simulation.

##### Current Efforts

In present, I am using the Monte-Carlo method for evaluation of integrals. But, it is compute intensive. Greater the precision, greater the amount of computation required since more random sample points are required for precise evaluation of integrals. Considering my requirement of precisions up to $10^{-9}$, this method is not enough to produce satisfactory accuracy in simulation since computing power is practically limited.

##### Expectations

To achieve satisfactory level of accuracy, I expect to find an analytical solution (rather than the numerical one being used presently). The best case is to have a proper solution, but, concepts like power-series expansion of integral would also be great.